# Using dynamic keys in an object (ie [x: string]: T), how can I make one key an exception?

Tags: typescript

Below I have an object with uses a dynamic key of string. I know there will never be overlap between the dynamic key and `_meta` in real use, but how can I explicitly tell typescript that `_meta` should always be treated as the object specified, rather than as `Highlight`?

```js
type FullHighlighter = {
    _meta: { /* special object */ }
    [highlightID : string] : Highlight
}
// Property '_meta' of type 'string' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'Highlight'
```

For example I thought this might work, but it didn't:

```js
type FullHighlighter = {
    _meta: { /* special object */ }
    [highlightID : Exclude<string, "_meta">] : Highlight
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide more code?

Comment: oh sorry, is `[highlightId: stirng]` a property of type `FullHIghlighter`?

Comment: Yes there's not really much more than needed that wouldn't just add confusion. `FullHighlighter` and `Highlight` can be replaced with anything  (ie, `Animal` and `number` respectively). The issue is `string` overlapping with `_meta` whereas I would like `_meta` to be an exception and have a different type than that specified in the `string` key type definition

Comment: It is partialy possible to do. See [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3yZbw). However, you should add prefix to each ID. If it is not allowed, you can use numbers for id, see [here](https://tsplay.dev/wXK6oW)

Comment: No, there is no specific type in TypeScript that works how you want.  Please see the answer to the linked question for more information.